# What is the relation between different generalizations of linear programming?

Tags: convex-optimization, linear-programming, sums-of-squares, semidefinite-programming

Linear programming subsumed by each of

1. Semidefinite programming (SDP)
2. Convex programming (CXP)
3. SOS programming (SSP)

Is there any relation between each pair in the three?

Are all three equivalent in expressive capability?

Comment: $LP\subset SDP\subset SSP\subset CXP$. Also, you can encode SSP as SDP by lifting. These slides are relevant: http://www.mit.edu/~parrilo/pubs/talkfiles/Eckman.pdf

Comment: So it is rather $LP\subset_{poly} SDP=_{poly}SSP\subset_{poly} CXP$? By subscript $poly$ I mean you are blowing up the program only polynomially. So the inclusions are upto polynomial blowup?